# Reasoning, order of age

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, soft-question

Hari(H), Gita(G), Irfan(I) and Saira(S) are siblings (i.e., brothers and sisters). All were born on 1st January. The age difference between any two successive siblings (that is born one after another) is less than three years. Given the following facts:

- Hari's age + Gita's age > Irfan's age + Saira's age
- The age difference between Gita and Saira is one year. However Gita is not the oldest and Saira is not the youngest.
- There are no twins.

In what order they were born (oldest first)?

1. HSIG
2. SGHI
3. IGSH
4. IHSG

---

My attempt :

$H + G > I + S$

$G – S = 1$ OR $S – G = 1$

$G$ is not the oldest and $S$ is not the youngest.
We need to try all options one by one.

I guess option $(2)$ is true.

> Can you explain little bit please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the four given options, 1 is impossible since G and S would be more than $1$ year different in age.  Options 3 and 4 are both impossible since in both those cases you would have I + S $>$ H + G.

That leaves only option 2.  However, it looks to me like there are some other birth orders consistent with the given information, just not among the options provided.  These orders are also possible (with possible ages given in parentheses):  H(11), G(9), S(8), I(6); or 
H(11), I(9), S(8), G(7).